# SQLite "split" row into multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

**Is there a way to "split" one row into multiple rows?**

My problem is that I have table of edges where patternID is the id of the edge and sourceStationID and targetStationID are the ids that the edge connects:

**Patterns:**

```
patternID | sourceStationID | targetStationID
1|1|2
2|1|6
3|1|3
4|1|4
5|4|6
6|5|6
```

I also have table of Hubs where I can transfer:

**Hubs:**

```
hubID
4
5
```

I need to get out of those data patternIDs that connect stations 1->6 exactly via one hub. So the result of query should be:

```
4
5
```

I did that by joining patterns table with hubs table and again with patterns table so i get:

```
patternID | sourceStationID | targetStationID | patternID | sourceStationID | targetStationID
4         | 1               | 4               | 5         | 4               | 6
```

**How can I split this row into two rows?**

edit:
Here is code that I use so far:

```
select t2a.patternID from
(
select * from `patterns`
join `hubs` on `targetStationID` = `hubID`
where `sourceStationID` = 1
) as t1a
join
(
select * from `patterns`
join `hubs` on `sourceStationID` = `hubID`
where `targetStationID` = 6
) as t2a
on t1a.hubID = t2a.hubID
union
select t1b.patternID from
(
select * from `patterns`
join `hubs` on `targetStationID` = `hubID`
where `sourceStationID` = 1
) as t1b
join
(
select * from `patterns`
join `hubs` on `sourceStationID` = `hubID`
where `targetStationID` = 6
) as t2b
on t1b.hubID = t2b.hubID;
```

It's working but I'm using the same select twice.

Comment: Can you post your query to see what you are selecting so we can offer suggested changes.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the WITH clause, for recursive statments. On close example being: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cd37dd9f-17c5-4df5-b072-5a9e51d1798d/show-all-children-and-grandchildren-for-parent-hierarchically?forum=transactsql

Comment: Why is the result 4 and 6? Shouldn't it be 4 and 5? You said they were patternIDs.

Comment: Frazz, you're right. It should be 4 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

Updating my answer to hopefully be closer to what you wanted. As far as I understand your question, this seems to give what you requested. The view could be avoided, with its join done in the CTE instead:

```
C:\Users\DDevienne>sqlite3
SQLite version 3.8.4.3 2014-04-03 16:53:12
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> create table edges (id integer primary key autoincrement, beg int, end int);
sqlite> insert into edges (beg, end) values (1, 2), (1, 6), (1, 3), (1, 4), (4, 6), (5, 6);
sqlite> create view edges2 as
   ...> select start.id as beg_id, start.beg as beg, start.end as hub, finish.id as end_id, finish.end as end
   ...> from edges start, edges finish
   ...> where start.end = finish.beg;
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> select * from edges2;
beg_id|beg|hub|end_id|end
4|1|4|5|6
sqlite> create table hubs (id integer primary key);
sqlite> insert into hubs values (4), (5);
sqlite> with hub_edges(beg_id, beg, hub, end_id, end) as (
   ...> select edges2.* from edges2, hubs where edges2.hub = hubs.id
   ...> )
   ...> select beg_id as id, beg, hub as end from hub_edges
   ...> union all
   ...> select end_id as id, hub as beg, end from hub_edges;
id|beg|end
4|1|4
5|4|6
sqlite>
```

Warning: This requires the latest SQLite (3.8.4.3), and won't work with 3.8.3.x

Comment: It's important to have the data structured as I described because I'm using patternID as foreign key in another table.